# Hooking Linux machine to secondary router/ISP: how to setup routing correctly?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, opensuse, multi-homed

**Abstract:**

I have (I presume routing) issues when adding a secondary ISP to my existing network setup: incoming traffic through `Router1` is not answered, but local traffic and incoming through `Router0` is working fine.

How can I keep the parts that currently function well working, while making incoming traffic through `Router1` work?

**Elaboration:**

I've sketched a diagram below with the bare essentials of the situation (in practice there are more devices on each LAN, but they do not matter).

This is the situation:

- I have two internal networks: `LAN0` is `192.168.x.0/24` and `LAN1` is `192.168.y.0/24`. Both work fine for internal traffic (for instance [http](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) using [cURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL)).
- `LAN0` has always been connected through `Router0` and `ISP0` to the `Internet`.
- `LAN1` always had `Router1`, but is now connected through `ISP1` to the `Internet`.
- Machines only on `LAN0` and having a default route through `Router0` work fine for outgoing and incoming traffic.
- Machines only on `LAN1` and having a default route through `Router1` work fine for outgoing and incoming traffic.
- Internal traffic on `LAN0` and `LAN1` has always worked fine.
- Incoming traffic through `Router1` for `WindowsB` arrives correctly: I can connect to it over RDP from `WindowsC`.
- Incoming traffic through `Router1` for `LinuxB` arrives (according to [tcpdump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpdump)), but not answered back as a `curl http://e.f.g.h` fron `LinuxC` shows with a [tcpdump on](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html#lbAG) `LinuxB` shows:

It shows only packets that - according to the [tcpdump output format](http://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html#lbAG) - have a [SYN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SYN_(TCP)#CONNECTION-ESTABLISHMENT) flag set:

```
LinuxB:/tmp/LinuxB.eth1.80 # tcpdump -i eth1 'port 80'
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
13:35:19.489779 IP i.j.k.l.57512 > 192.168.y.2.http: Flags [S], seq 816356596, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 1287047182 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
13:35:19.788841 IP i.j.k.l.57512 > 192.168.y.2.http: Flags [S], seq 816356596, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 1287047478 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
13:35:19.888835 IP i.j.k.l.57512 > 192.168.y.2.http: Flags [S], seq 816356596, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 1287047578 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
13:35:19.989412 IP i.j.k.l.57512 > 192.168.y.2.http: Flags [S], seq 816356596, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 1287047678 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
13:35:20.089685 IP i.j.k.l.57512 > 192.168.y.2.http: Flags [S], seq 816356596, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 1287047778 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
13:35:20.190836 IP i.j.k.l.57512 > 192.168.y.2.http: Flags [S], seq 816356596, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 1287047877 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
13:35:20.392123 IP i.j.k.l.57512 > 192.168.y.2.http: Flags [S], seq 816356596, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 1287048072 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
13:35:20.693692 IP i.j.k.l.57512 > 192.168.y.2.http: Flags [S], seq 816356596, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,eol], length 0
13:35:21.197162 IP i.j.k.l.57512 > 192.168.y.2.http: Flags [S], seq 816356596, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,eol], length 0
13:35:22.204134 IP i.j.k.l.57512 > 192.168.y.2.http: Flags [S], seq 816356596, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,eol], length 0
13:35:24.115961 IP i.j.k.l.57512 > 192.168.y.2.http: Flags [S], seq 816356596, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,eol], length 0
13:35:27.852374 IP i.j.k.l.57512 > 192.168.y.2.http: Flags [S], seq 816356596, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,eol], length 0
13:35:31.967049 IP i.j.k.l.57512 > 192.168.y.2.http: Flags [S], seq 816356596, win 65535, options [mss 1460,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

This is the `LinuxB` route table:

```
LinuxB:/tmp/LinuxB.eth1.80 # route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.x.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
loopback        *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.x.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.x.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

Since connecting over RDP from `WindowsC` to `WindowsB` works fine, I resume this is indeed a routing problem. This is the `WindowsB` route table:

```
C:\temp>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
0x1 ........................... MS TCP Loopback interface
0x2 ...00 0c 29 35 77 e1 ...... AMD PCNET Family PCI Ethernet Adapter - Packet Scheduler Miniport
0x3 ...00 0c 29 35 77 eb ...... VMware Accelerated AMD PCNet Adapter - Packet Scheduler Miniport
===========================================================================
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.x.1     192.168.x.4      10
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.y.1     192.168.y.4       5
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1       1
      192.168.x.0    255.255.255.0      192.168.x.4     192.168.x.4      10
      192.168.x.4  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1      10
    192.168.x.255  255.255.255.255      192.168.x.4     192.168.x.4      10
      192.168.y.0    255.255.255.0      192.168.y.4     192.168.y.4      10
      192.168.y.4  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1      10
    192.168.y.255  255.255.255.255      192.168.y.4     192.168.y.4      10
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      192.168.x.4     192.168.x.4      10
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      192.168.y.4     192.168.y.4      10
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      192.168.x.4     192.168.x.4       1
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      192.168.y.4     192.168.y.4       1
Default Gateway:       192.168.y.1
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.y.1       5
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.x.1      10
```

So how can I get the routing on `LinuxB` to be like this:

- keep default route on `LinuxB` to `192.168.x.1` so outgoing traffic keeps using `Router0`/`ISP0`
- keep answering incoming requests coming from `LAN0` on `LAN0`
- keep answering incoming requests coming from `LAN1` on `LAN1`
- keep answering incoming requests through `Router0` (`a.b.c.d`/`192.168.x.1`) via `192.168.x.1`
- start answering incoming requests through `Router1` (`e.f.g.h`/`192.168.y.1`) via `192.168.y.1`
- bonus: have `Router1` fail-over or load-balance with `Router0`

**Postscript:**

The [PNG image below](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/ZPJRQeD048RlzocMt7TqZPGaq99KA1H2A3tGo-9XhIRgfhesaT9thwwhSJtGNkxivym_C_-wphYTyZoE46BEdheSRyCaFs_mDyAOya37DvWi3I3N2pZ3l0wIJh0GGO_wTXxnzvJbd2gVaFBsnD93LcMQkNaQuO3puqhJBemnQo0o1HKLzADel1lNQ8nfDFxGs6P-2nEFdRA9tEPORlE_kRURdIxo9fHNtIgShXccWf89jEYXJrN9LEyAji415xoXs7eTFajFTkfTmDL2nrUttHcMaL5mFbyiLTGKiRuSqfL3mOSF2CPcfygHO4zECPJJW7qvnK3Em_DZFPhxqA4fthsyAdUrJijs8efZvj6uSvkKVPJZ5yHBGB4LiTphUT3gzXd27WuGJHfU3h4oks-7qT3iigtPm8vAcGGO7E5JAHDdF7EnzhNgrBWygFQsKm39TmuWV8c4EQk3U5hjiNaFAawGCAY24nMNtqjtje2q1sfSMuQg5Q76DlMP8B6twY2tWCIob42pdqQ5fOIQoI6qfebN_k1-0G00) is generated on [UML](http://www.uml.org/) text through the free online [PlantUML](https://www.plantuml.com/) engine. If you want to see the original UML text, paste the [PNG image link](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/ZPJRQeD048RlzocMt7TqZPGaq99KA1H2A3tGo-9XhIRgfhesaT9thwwhSJtGNkxivym_C_-wphYTyZoE46BEdheSRyCaFs_mDyAOya37DvWi3I3N2pZ3l0wIJh0GGO_wTXxnzvJbd2gVaFBsnD93LcMQkNaQuO3puqhJBemnQo0o1HKLzADel1lNQ8nfDFxGs6P-2nEFdRA9tEPORlE_kRURdIxo9fHNtIgShXccWf89jEYXJrN9LEyAji415xoXs7eTFajFTkfTmDL2nrUttHcMaL5mFbyiLTGKiRuSqfL3mOSF2CPcfygHO4zECPJJW7qvnK3Em_DZFPhxqA4fthsyAdUrJijs8efZvj6uSvkKVPJZ5yHBGB4LiTphUT3gzXd27WuGJHfU3h4oks-7qT3iigtPm8vAcGGO7E5JAHDdF7EnzhNgrBWygFQsKm39TmuWV8c4EQk3U5hjiNaFAawGCAY24nMNtqjtje2q1sfSMuQg5Q76DlMP8B6twY2tWCIob42pdqQ5fOIQoI6qfebN_k1-0G00) into this [PlantUML form](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/form), then press `Submit`.

[image]

Comment: Just found an interesting answer at http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/23345/69111 which I'm investigating to see if it applies to my case, and how to implement it using `yast`.

Comment: `Yast` seems out for doing complex routing and `route` seems to be deprecated in favour of `ip`. See http://opensuse.14.x6.nabble.com/yast2-advanced-routing-td3083578.html and https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_basicnet_manconf.html

Comment: Your linked solution at unix.stackexchange is going in the right direction, and would solve the linux problem -- the linux node has two separate routing tables, and uses the appropriate table depending on which interface the connection was initiated on.  I am not aware of any such solution for Windows.  Unless there is a real need for two subnets, I would get rid of one and use one router for both ISPs.  You can buy routers that can deal with two WANs properly, or you could use another Linux system to do it, which would simplify the routing on the systems behind it.

Comment: @DavidMackintosh in the future I will. This is temporary: fiber is actually DSL, and going to move to a different fiber address. The machine is DNS and MX, so I want it to be accessible from two ISPs to have continuity as I'm not sure if DSL will be shutdown before or after fiber becomes active.

Answer (score 1):

I had a shell script for doing something like that a long-long time ago but, sorry, could find it. So I can only give you the pointers to the solutions I implemented back then.
I'm writting mostly from memory so some examples are missing:

1. I had one routing table per uplink (ip route ... table 101, ip route ... table 102). That goes into /etc/iproute2/rt_tables.

   101 isp1
   102 isp2

   You need to setup those tables also:

   ip route add default via $Gateway1 dev $Interface1 table isp1
   ip route add default via $Gateway2 dev $Interface2 table isp2

   #Don't forget the default table:

   ip route add default via $DefaultGateway dev $DefaultInterface
2. Enable iptables connection tracking (modprobe nf_conntrack)
3. Set an iptables rule for NEW incoming connections to -j MARK the packets somehow (ie: 0x201, 0x202)
4. Set an ip rule that ensure that traffic going out trhough an interface uses the right routing table

   ip rule add from $Ip1 table isp1
   ip rule add from $Ip2 table isp2
5. Set an ip rule (ip rule add ...) stating that "packets marked 0x201 shall lookup routing table 201", one rule for every uplink.

With everything in place you should be able to receive and initiate connections with any wan uplink and even balance outgoing connections.

Those would be the basics. Iptables + "ip route" + "ip rule" and you're good to go.